# Linq-to-Xml prefix parse error

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am currently trying to learn how to parse data, and its a bit confusing. can someone check out my code and see what I'm doing wrong or if im even heading in the right direction.

XML File:

```
<xml xmlns:a='BLAH'
     xmlns:b='BLAH'
     xmlns:c='BLAH'
     xmlns:d='BLAH'>
  <a:info>
   <b:cat Option1='blah' Option2='blah' Option3='blah' />
  </a:info>
</xml>
```

C# Code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(richTextBox2.Text);

XmlNamespaceManager man = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
man.AddNamespace("a", "BLAH");
man.AddNamespace("b", "BLAH");
man.AddNamespace("c", "BLAH");
man.AddNamespace("d", "BLAH");

XmlNode temps = doc.SelectSingleNode("/a:info/b:cat/Option1/", man);

richTextBox1.Text = temps.InnerText;
```

I am new to C#, I cant find a good example ***explaining*** how to successfully use loops to find more then one:

```
<b:chat />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong API if you're looking for LINQ to XML. Use the XDocument class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the following input XML-document (please note namespace URLs):

```
<xml xmlns:a='http://localhost/scheme_a'
     xmlns:b='http://localhost/scheme_b'
     xmlns:c='http://localhost/scheme_c'
     xmlns:d='http://localhost/scheme_d'>
    <a:info>
       <b:cat Option1='1' Option2='1' Option3='1' />
    </a:info>

    <a:info>
       <b:cat Option1='2' Option2='2' Option3='2' />
    </a:info>
</xml>
```

There are the ways to get all `<b:chat />` elements.

1. [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) class:

   ```
   var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
   xmlDocument.Load(...);

   var xmlNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);
   xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("a", "http://localhost/scheme_a");
   xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("b", "http://localhost/scheme_b");
   xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("c", "http://localhost/scheme_c");
   xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("d", "http://localhost/scheme_d");

   var bCatNodes = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("/xml/a:info/b:cat", xmlNamespaceManager);
   var option1Attributes = bCatNodes.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(node => node.Attributes["Option1"]);

   // Also, all Option1 attributes can be retrieved directly using XPath:
   // var option1Attributes = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("/xml/a:info/b:cat/@Option1", xmlNamespaceManager).Cast<XmlAttribute>();
   ```
2. LINQ to XML [XDocument Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx). [XName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.aspx) can be passed with a namespace to [Descendants()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.descendants.aspx) and [Element()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.elements.aspx) methods.

   Use [Descendants()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.descendants.aspx) to get all `<b:chat />` elements.

   ```
   var xDocument = XDocument.Load(...);
   XNamespace xNamespace = "http://localhost/scheme_b";
   var xElements = xDocument.Descendants(xNamespace + "cat");

   // For example, get all the values of Option1 attribute for the b:chat elements:
   var options1 = xElements.Select(element => element.Attribute("Option1")).ToList();
   ```

Comment: Thank you Sergey, I am a little confused once its stored, in option1attributes how to I cast it to the textbox or choose the element?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add the values of *Option1* attribute to the `RichTextBox`?

Comment: Yes display the values into the rich textbox.everytime I load a file, it keeps telling me Illegal characters in path....